Exoplayer crashes if there is no Internet while downloading
Exoplayer, When i disconnect wifi while downloading a video,it crashes app and show below error, What can i do so the app will not crash and give a Toast instead that No Internet.
Here is the error
                        Process: com.a.acs2, PID: 22492
                        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No such service ComponentInfo{com.a.acs2/androidx.media3.exoplayer.scheduler.PlatformScheduler$PlatformSchedulerService}
                            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1560)
                            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1509)
                            at android.app.job.IJobScheduler$Stub$Proxy.schedule(IJobScheduler.java:122)
                            at android.app.JobSchedulerImpl.schedule(JobSchedulerImpl.java:42)
                            at androidx.media3.exoplayer.scheduler.PlatformScheduler.schedule(PlatformScheduler.java:86)
                            at androidx.media3.exoplayer.offline.DownloadService$DownloadManagerHelper.updateScheduler(DownloadService.java:1020)
                            at androidx.media3.exoplayer.offline.DownloadService.onIdle(DownloadService.java:838)
                            at androidx.media3.exoplayer.offline.DownloadService.access$700(DownloadService.java:56)
                            at androidx.media3.exoplayer.offline.DownloadService$DownloadManagerHelper.onIdle(DownloadService.java:1065)
                            at androidx.media3.exoplayer.offline.DownloadManager.onMessageProcessed(DownloadManager.java:650)
                            at androidx.media3.exoplayer.offline.DownloadManager.handleMainMessage(DownloadManager.java:607)
                            at androidx.media3.exoplayer.offline.DownloadManager.$r8$lambda$Ljilo1rwNXzdYIqsr2zvGuwCKeY(DownloadManager.java)
                            at androidx.media3.exoplayer.offline.DownloadManager$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.handleMessage(D8$$SyntheticClass:0)
                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5958)
                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1113)
                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:879)

i tried but find nothing on exoplayer doc

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Looks like when network connectivity is lost while downloading, exoplayer will try to schedule the download, probably to resume the download when connectivity is back.  And it's missing PlatformSchedulerService while trying to invoke it. Add this to your manifest and try again
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>

<service android:name="androidx.media3.exoplayer.scheduler.PlatformScheduler$PlatformSchedulerService"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
    android:exported="true"/>


Tnx,it magically works
